# Sendmail Invoked by Unknown Process

Tags: linux, networking, security, sendmail, drupal

On a webserver, I am seeing unknown processes invoking sendmail like

```
root      1544  1188  0 03:42 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: ./qBBJ2gNg014264 mail.furst.com.: user open
```

I have DROPed all SMTP destination ports via iptables. Have confirmed this by seeing SYN_SENT for such connections via netstat.

How can I find / stop / remove these unknown processes running sendmail?

UPDATE: The OP has said that the machine is running Drupal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your machine is running a web server with php and someone has managed to use it in order to send mail from the machine.

Comment: Yes. It does run Drupal (php)! What can I do to fix it!?

Comment: Added Drupal in the question tags for people who do Drupal may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the presented ps clip in your question is processing by sendmail for a specified queued mail entry on your local host -- nothing externally initiated (except for getting a local sendmail message from probably an application program running on the local server, invoked by some website program?).

Thus there is no unknown process here playing around with sendmail based on the information presented in your question.

Did you traceback to the process that invoked sendmail (i.e. process 1188 in this case?).

If you are asking how to stop all sendmail processing, then you could simply remove the sendmail package from your server.

Comment: yes. I figured that it was some local application program running these. But then, how should I locate such program and probably remove it? All I see is just `./qBBJ2gNg014264 mail.liuc.it. user open`

Comment: 1188 is sendmail itself. `root      1188     1  0 Nov20 ?        00:02:25 sendmail: accepting connections`